# Preallocate memory for vector of strings (C++ vector<string>)

Tags: c++, stl, memory-management

In C++, is there a clever (i.e. fast) way to pre-allocate memory for a vector of strings so that each element has some minimum size? The naive way I have is as follows:

```
vector<string> my_string_vector;
my_string_vector.resize(1000);
for (unsigned int ui=0; ui<1000; ui++)
   my_string_vector[ui].reserve(1024);
```

Many thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no fast way to do it.  You can get fewer lines of code, but you're still going to make one call to `reserve` for each `std::string` in the `std::vector`.

I believe [EASTL](https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL) or [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/pool/doc/index.html) may help, if you're willing to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to pre-allocate all of this memory at once is by implementing your own allocators, like so (code is not complete, as obviously allocators have more members that need to be supported):

```
class my_string_allocator {
public:
   char * allocate(size_type n, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint=0) {
      // ... grab a chunk from your pre-allocated pool ...
   }
};

typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, my_string_allocator> my_string;

class my_vector_allocator {
public:
   my_string * allocate(size_type n, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint=0) {
      // ... similar magic goes here ...
   }
}

vector<my_string, my_vector_allocator> my_string_vector(1000);
for (unsigned int ui=0; ui<1000; ui++)
   my_string_vector[ui].reserve(1024);  // Memory taken from pool; no allocation.
```

This is really only practical if you know exactly what you're allocating for the lifetime of these data structures, since more flexible allocation will require heap-management-like logic in your allocators.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a single string with a capacity of at least 1024, and then copy-construct it 1000 times into the vector.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::string s;
   s.reserve(1024);
   std::vector<std::string> my_string_vector(1000, s);
   std::cout << my_string_vector[42].capacity() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the copy constructor will copy the capacity. It **will** copy the size of the string.

Comment: I don't have the standard handy, so I can't say definitively. But, g++ 4.4.3 on Ubuntu does copy the capacity.

Comment: The copy constructor only guarantees that `capacity() >= size()`. See standard paragraph 21.4.2, Table 64.

Comment: I believe g++ uses copy-on-write, so all the copies are actually the same string, until some of them are changed.

Comment: So - just to be clear, this solution is implementation specific, although will work in g++?